# Import source project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to import a source Project in eclipse. The project is made by many folder like Classes (that contain .class files), src(that contain .java files) and many others. The source project and the instructions on how to set up eclipse are reported at [this link](http://www.prismmodelchecker.org/wiki/Developers/SettingUpEclipse). I tried to follow them but I haven't got anything. I think this is a simple thing but I'm new to eclipse.

My eclipse actual version is eclipse java neon 2.
My OS is ubuntu.

Comment: Are you able to select the project folder from `File > Import...`?

Comment: You could try creating a new project and then copying the files into it.

Comment: I try to import in this mode: import->Project from Folder or Archive->.. but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to create a new Project from the File Options and then select Project from existing sources which choosing the source directory.

Second approach could be to just use File > import Project wizard.